# Bind keyboard shortcut to bash function to interrupt sleep?

Tags: bash, triggers, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, i3

I have a collection of .jpg background images that I want to use as backgrounds for my i3-gaps desktop. Currently, I have these two lines in my i3 config file for my wallpapers.

```
exec --no-startup-id randomwallpaper
bindsym $mod+i exec --no-startup-id feh --bg-scale --randomize /home/user/Pictures/bgart/*.jpg
```

This is my randomwallpaper script. It uses feh to set an image and wal to create a colorscheme based off of it.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/Pictures/bgart
for file in $(ls); do
        shopt -s nullglob
        for i in *.jpg; do
                feh --bg-scale --randomize /home/user/Pictures/bgart/$i
                wal -q -i $i
                sleep 300
        done
done
```

On startup, randomwallpaper starts and every 5 minutes the wallpaper changes along with the colorscheme. However, I can also press Win+I to manually switch to a random wallpaper. Is it possible to add a trigger of some sort to interrupt the cycle? Maybe have the script as a function and add a key to call it? That way, I can have the above script running and if I get bored of the wallpaper, I can switch to another with Win+I and still have it change 5 minutes later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you modified your `bash` with a built-in sleep, you can kill the sleep command. The script will then proceed to the next command as if `sleep` terminated normally. The only tricky part is to identify the correct process to kill. Here I assume that there is only one `randomwallpaper` process running on your system:

```
exec --no-startup-id randomwallpaper
bindsym $mod+i exec --no-startup-id sh -c 'pkill -P $(pgrep -ox randomwallpaper) sleep'
```

By the way; Your script could use some improvement. For instance, the variable `file` is unused and `--randomize` has no effect since you only supply one picture.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
cd /home/user/Pictures/bgart
while true; do
  i=$(shuf -en1 ./*.jpg)
  if [ -n "$i" ]; then
    feh --bg-scale "$i"
    wal -q -i "$i"
  fi
  sleep 300
done
```

Comment: That seems like exactly what I need, thank you. Yes, my script was roughly adapted from a similar script, thanks for improving it.

Comment: <del>Actually, it seems the keybind is working in killing the sleep process, but wal is not changing the colorscheme to the new image. Opening a new terminal still has the colorscheme of the first image. Not sure why</del> Nevermind, it was just being slow. Thanks again